# Using margin along side position

Tags: css

I am using the css below and I get the height fine but it looses the `margin: 0 auto`.  How can I change the css so that I get the full window height but also have the div center?

**CSS:**

```
.container{
    width:960px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:url('../img/bg.png') repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could lead you to further problems but basic idea is to force `body` and `html` to has `100%` height

HTML

```
<div class="page">
    content
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}

.page {
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:300px;
    background:green
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/fk9N3/

**Edit:** sorry, when i say further problems, i meant it will be tricky to stretch a nested div to stretch full height of the window as in that case you'd have to force every element in the chain to have `min-height:100%;`

Something like below

```
<div class="some-wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="some-other-div">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

to make `.some-other-div` to be the fullheight of the window - you'd have to add `min-height:100%;` to `.some-wrapper, .content-wrapper` which is kinda ugly